# Remove widgets from p:dashboard via dragging out

Tags: primefaces, drag-and-drop, dashboard

I'd like to add support to removing the widgets from `p:dashboard` via dragging the panel out of dashboard, such as in WordPress admin panel.

I've found out the examples of dragging the widgets between 2 dashboards, but in my case I need to have callback when the element is dragged out of dashboard, no matter where. The widget would be than removed. However, I couldn't find any example for such behaviour.

What components/tools to use to implement such functionality? I'm using **PrimeFaces 3.4**.

Answer (score 0):

Use draggable component with dashboard keyword;

```
 <p:draggable for="widget" dashboard=":dbForm:dashboard"/>
```

And check this solutions on forum page of primefaces: [Dashboard Drag and Drop](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17608)

Hope it'll help you.
Good Luck!